# Is there any service that sends messages to smart contracts in a pre-determined future time?

Tags: contract-invocation, server-side, blockchain-as-a-service

Is there any service that sends messages to smart contracts in a pre-determined future time?

Need also to re-send the message if the gas was low and it is stalled too long.

Comment: Oraclize, Chainlink... Search for *Ethereum Oracles* on Google.

Comment: @goodvibration See also https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/3043 - my proposal to make it built-in in the Ethereum blockchain!

Comment: That is not possible **by the definition of the Ethereum blockchain**.

Comment: @goodvibration My proposal is to change the "definition" (upgrade the protocol a little).

Comment: Anyway, how is that proposal related to this question?

Comment: @goodvibration That proposal is a better solution of the issue of this question.

Comment: BTW, it is not a good question IMO. Too general, and not providing any technical details of the actual requirements. Other than suggesting for you to search *ethereum oracles* on google, there is nothing much to say about it.

Comment: @porton Do you think it is a good idea to have miners being required to "listen" for an arbitrary number of potential "ready" events? Checking every block to see which ones are ready and then subsequently firing them? How much gas do you think that would actually cost? It doesn't sound viable or reasonable to me. It would be far more viable to have this sort of thing implemented on L2.

Comment: @Jay Could limit to a certain number of "readies" per block, laying aside other for the future. Can order by gas (well, sorting takes CPU).

Comment: @porton Yes, you can limit the "readies" per block, but you still need to scan an arbitrary number of "pending" to check for that limit of "readies".